# When debugging a C++ program with GDB the "next" command seems to skip source lines

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

When I debug my C++ program, I set a breakpoint on the `main` function. When the program starts running, it seems to have skipped several lines of source before the line at which it stops. What's the problem?

[image: Screenshot illustrating the problem]

Comment: Currently, the problem is you've provided not a shred of source code or anything remotely substantial to warrant anything resembling an answer.

Comment: Please show msopen.cpp

Answer (score 4):

Your program is probably compiled with optimisation enabled, which means that the lines of source are not necessarily sequentially translated into machine code.  Under optimisation, the execution of different parts of the source code can be re-ordered and interleaved - this is likely what you're seeing.

If you want to step through your source code in a simple, sequential line-by-line manner you will need to compile with no optimisation (`-O0`).

Alternatively, if you understand machine code you can use:

```
set disassemble-next-line on
```

which will show you the disassembly of the code that the debugger is stopped on alongside the source code line it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have symbols for your program, as GDB happily reads them. However, do you have the source in the original place or are you perhaps debugging on a different machine?

What does:

```
info source
```

give you when you enter it on the command prompt? It should give you something along the lines of:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is hello.c
Compilation directory is /home/username/source
Located in /home/username/source/hello.c
Contains 7 lines.
Source language is c.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Includes preprocessor macro info.
```

if GDB has debug symbols and source available.

From the output, however, it looks like this part *should* be fine, so caf is likely right that this is about the optimization level of your compiler.

Keep in mind that this is the very reason for debug versus release settings. **During development** you'll perhaps want `-O0` or `-O1` combined with `-ggdb -g3` if you're using GCC to compile. For other compilers the settings may be different. **For a release** you'll probably want to use the highest safe optimization value (see [this link](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gcc-optimization.xml)), `-O2` for `gcc` or `-O3` if you are using one of the widely used architectures and aren't afraid of nasty surprises.

Either way if you are serious about software development and consequently debugging, you should learn the very basics of the assembly language for your target CPUs. Why? Because sometimes the optimizer, especially in GCC, goes haywire and does stupid things even when you tell it to not trust your code, such as with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. I've encountered cases where it would happily use instructions on a SPARC which are supposed to be used only on aligned data, but there was no guarantee that the data we gave it was aligned. Anyway, it's the very reason [Gentoo recommends `-O2`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gcc-optimization.xml) instead of any higher value for optimization. If you don't know why an assembly instruction does what it does or why your program does something silly and you can't take the magnifying glass and step down to the assembly level, you'll be lost.

#### How to see the assembly code in GDB

As [pointed out by caf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184340/476371) you can use `set disassemble-next-line on` to see the disassembly at the current program counter if you are using GDB 7.0 or newer. On older GDB versions you may resort to the trusty old [`display` command](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html#Auto-Display):

```
disp/i $pc
```

which sets an automatic display for the program counter (`$pc`). Perhaps a better and visually more appealing alternative, especially if you have a lot of screen estate, is to use `layout asm` and `layout regs` combined in GDB. See the following screen shot:

[image: layouts asm and regs combined in GDB]